# How to set values in rails without form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, oncreate

We have an field in the Database which should be set automatic as an UUID String. how do we that. the view doesn't contain this field because it will be autogenerated.
Our new-form will called so.

```
def new
  @list = List.new
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
end
```

Our create-action is here

```
def create
  @list = List.new(params[:list])
  @list = list.create!(params[:list]) 
end
```

If we try this

```
@list.admin_key = UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s
```

we get an validation error and the field is empty. the controller require

```
require 'uuidtools'
```

Our validation for the field is that is prencense and unique

```
validates :admin_key,
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => true
```

How did we get the admin_key into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u have to do this in your model

```
before_validation(:on => :create) do
  self.admin_key = UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s
end
```